# Cron-like scheduling in Airflow

Tags: airflow

Data is published every Monday morning via FTP server. Each week directory has a new archive with the name like `data_YYYYMMDD.zip`.

My DAG has `schedule_interval = '0 8 * * 1'`. Python Operator derives file name from `ds` variable and downloads the file. Then file name is passed to subsequent operators (4 in parallel) via XCom.

The issue that this week data is received next week. I'm aware that Airflow runs my job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

My workaround is to use `next_execution_date` variable instead of `ds` variable.

In Airflow, is there a way remove one week (one schedule) delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [airflow.macros.ds_add](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#id11) function to add/subtract number of days to default **ds** date macro.

```
EXEC_DATE = '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7) }}'
```

Comment: I do not use templates but let me check. Also, should have mentioned that time arithmetics might not be an ideal  solution